# Mandrill bcc is not appearing in the mail

Tags: php, email, smtp

In Mandrill api using php,when I am adding a bcc using following code,the mail is sent successfully but the bcc line is not appearing in the mail details of inbox mail.

```
"to": [
{
"email": "abc@abc.com",
"name": "abc"
},
{"email": "xyz@xyz.com", "type": "cc"},
{"email": "pqr@pqr.com", "type": "bcc"}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it is supposed to be. `BCC` is never shown to recipients.

Comment: I have checked normally,but bcc shows in the email details of the recipient

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy "Bcc: Blind carbon copy to tertiary recipients who receive the message. The primary and secondary recipients cannot see the tertiary recipients. Depending on email software, the tertiary recipients may only see their own email address in Bcc, or they may see the email addresses of all recipients." The whole point of `BCC` is to hide additional recipients.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

Parameters **bcc_address** contain an optional address to receive an exact copy of each recipient's email

```
Mandrill Docs with Example https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html
```